# Returning contents of a text file and printing different value

Tags: python

I am making a Recipe book, at the moment I have the ability to create a recipe, but now I am starting to build the module of searching and displaying stored recipes.

At the moment I have a .txt document with the contents along the lines of:

> Williams Special Recipe
>
> Ingredients:
>
> bread:  120 grams 
>   butter:  1234 grams
>
> Recipe Serves: 12

I then ask the user how many they are serving and based on how many the recipe serves, I need to multiply all the ingredients quantity by that number. I then need to print that off with the full recipe again.

I was wondering how I would go about achieving this result, not asking specifically for a coded response as an answer, but I would greatly appreciate how I would approach this task and any specific functions required.

I have also included my code so far, I appreciate the fact it is incredibly un-organised at the moment, and probably hard to understand, but I included it for any reference.

(I have also created a .txt file of all the created recipes which will be implemented later on as a way of displaying to the user all recipes, but at the moment it is just set up for searching.)

```
#Recipe Task

import os.path

def file_(n):
    if n == "listR" :
        list_f = open("list_recipes.txt", "a+")
        list_f.write(new_name + "\n")
    if n == "oar": #open append read
        f=open(new_name + ".txt","a+")
    elif n == "c": #closes file
        f.close()


def print_line(x): #ease of printing multiple lines to break up text
    for c in range(x):
        print ""

def new_ingredients(): #adding new ingredients
    f.write("Ingredients:" + "\n" + "\n")
    fin_ingredient = False
    while fin_ingredient != True :
        input_ingredient = raw_input("New ingredient:" + "\n").lower()
        split_ingred = input_ingredient.split()
        if input_ingredient == "stop": #stops asking questions when user types 'stop'
            fin_ingredient = True
        else :
            f.write(split_ingred[0] + ":" + "  " + split_ingred[1] + " " + split_ingred[2] + "\n")

def search_recipe(n): #searching for recipes
    n = n + ".txt"
    if os.path.isfile('/Users/wjpreston/Desktop/' + n) == True :
        print "Recipe Found..."
        found_recipe = open(n)
        print found_recipe.read()
        append_serving = raw_input("Would you like to change the number of people you are serving?" + "\n").lower()
        if append_serving == "yes" :
            appended_serving = input("How many would you like to serve?" + "\n")

            with open(n) as f:  #here is my issue - not sure where to go with this!!
                list_recipe = f.readlines()   

            found_recipe.close()
        else :
            print "fail"



    else:
        print "No existing recipes under that name have been found."







print "Welcome to your Recipe Book"
print_line(3)

recipe_phase = raw_input("Are you 'creating' a recipe or 'viewing' an existing one?" + "\n").lower()

if recipe_phase == "creating":

    new_name = raw_input("Name of Recipe: " + "\n")
    file_("listR")
    file_("oar")
    f.write("------------" + "\n" + new_name + "\n" + "\n")
    print "Ingrediants required in the format 'ingredient quantity unit' - type 'stop' to end process"
    new_ingredients()
    new_num = input("Number serving:    ")
    f.write("\n" + "Recipe Serves: " + str(new_num) + "\n" "\n" + "\n")
    file_("c")



elif recipe_phase == "viewing":
    search = raw_input("Search for recipe: ")
    search_recipe(search)
```

Comment: This question is ... pretty broad - I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. But appreciate the response nevertheless. I am trying to find away of allowing the recipe to be stored in a separate text file and then recalled when searched for but returned with different values in the ingredients depending on how many people are being served. So for 120 grams this serves 12 people. But I am serving 24, thus I want it to print of 240 grams of this ingredient. I want to return a different value to the user. Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the specialist in processing strings, but I'd approach your problem following way:
Save each ingredient on a new line.
Split the loaded string by "\n".
Then process the list with some for-loops while creating two dicts, one for the actual data

```
 e.g. {"bread": 4, "butter": 7}
```

and one for the types of each ingredient:

```
 e.g. {"bread": grams, "butter": grams}
```

The you should also save how many serves the recipe is written for, and maybe the order of the ingredients (dicts get stored in a random order):

```
e.g. ["bread", "butter"]
```

After that, you can ask your costumer how many serves he has and then finally calculate and print the final results.

```
   for ing in ing_order:
       print ing+":", ing_amount[ing]*requested_serves/default_seves, ing_types[ing]
```

...hopyfully you still have enough challange, and hopefully I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, for some reason in the formatting of the recipe included above is wrong, the ingredients are all on there own line. Thank you very much for your reply though, greatly appreciate your efforts in that. I understand what you are doing and will likely go for your approach thank you. One question is that, I understand the way of storing each line of the text file in a list, however, how do I determine whether this is an ingredient field in which I need to apply the above rule?

Comment: @WJPreston
Create a variable called `ingredients`. Process the list with a for-loop. If the current element is `"Ingredients:"`, set the `ingredients` to `True`. Then, also in the for loop you can add some "if" statements, e.g. `if element[:13] == "Recipe Serves": process_serves, elif ingredients == True: process_ingredient`. There certainly are more elegant ways (maybe you find one?), but at least you have an idea.

Comment: Ahh I am beginning to understand more now, thank you very much for your efforts. I am new to python and greatly appreciate the responses.